# How to call a function from a different file in python?

Tags: python, image, function

The files are in the same directory.
This is the function that i am trying to import into a different file:

```
RedInfantry = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\a level computer science\Coursework\Week\Red team\InfantryRedV20.gif"
screen.addshape(RedInfantry)

#Red Infantry
def InfantryRed(x, y):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.shape(RedInfantry)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    Health = 10
    Armour = 0
    Attack = 1
    Movement = 2
    Capture = True

    return turtle
```

This is what i have tried to do:

```
from ImagesV4 import *
import turtle

ImagesV4.InfantryRed(200,200)
screen.update()
```

The image will not come onto the screen and no errors when i run the code, just an empty screen.

Comment: If you import functions like that - using `from module import *` - you don't need to prefix them with module name, so `InfantryRed(200,200)` will suffice. Also, what was, in your opinion, the value of `screen` at the time `screen.addshape(RedInfantry)` was executed, and why do you think so?

Answer (score 2):

```
import ImagesV4 as im 


im.InfantryRed(200,200)
im.screen.update()
im.screen.exitonclick()  #using this for screen to hold
```

Comment: It did not work, i tried that and it still shows an empty screen

Comment: Do you have these two lines in the 1st  code , its worked fine with me    `from turtle import*`

    `screen = Screen()`